# Book involving a protagonist in control of a new kind of spaceship, who visits human colonies which are all in danger from a superior enemy

Tags: story-identification, books, space

I'm looking for the name of a mid-to-late century sci-fi book. I recall little of the book, other than enjoying it.

The main protagonist is a human male who somehow ends up in control of a new kind of new kind of jump or FTL ship.  He visits different human colonies in his little portion of the galaxy, but the colonies are all in danger from a superior enemy from some other quadrant (possibly human also).

There's mention of a 400,000-year-old crab-like race that builds cool ships, and whenever I think about it I see the words "guardians of/on/over(?) the horizon" in my mind... maybe a chapter title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, when you say _"mid-to-late century,"_ I'm guessing you mean _20th_ century?

Comment: [Kren of the Mitchegai](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/245809.Kren_of_the_Mitchegai) has some vague similarities. There is an ancient crab like race and the Mitchegai are an alien race threatening a region of human occupied worlds. But the resemblance is too vague to make it worth posting as an answer.

Comment: It was maybe 15 years ago when I read it. That being said, the book was missing g it's front cover and was fairly aged in appearance.  Yes the latter half of the 20th century. I wish I could remember more about it.  The crablike race was either 400000 yrs old or 400K light years away and they were more observers than anything but I think the protagonist needed to reach them for something involving saving earth from the coming invasion...maybe :)